# https with nginx and docker compose not working

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, certbot

Please I need some assistance. Your contributions will be greatly appreciated

I am trying to add ssl to my nginx and docker compose configuration.
Currently, everything works fine with http, but it won't work with https.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web_gunicorn:
    image: ACCT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/web_gunicorn:latest
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    # env_file:
    #   - .env  
    pull_policy: always
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      - PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
  nginx:
    image: ACCT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest
    pull_policy: always
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot 
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - web_gunicorn
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot 
    depends_on:
      - nginx  
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"    
        
volumes:
  static:
  media:
```

Here is my nginx.conf configuration that works (http)

```
upstream web {
    server web_gunicorn:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    
    location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.11;
        proxy_pass http://web;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;    
        }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /media/;
    }
    
}
```

Here is my nginx.conf configuration that does not work (http and https)

```
upstream web {
    server web_gunicorn:8000;
}

    server {

        location / {
            resolver 127.0.0.11;
            proxy_pass http://web;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;    
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /static/;
        }
        location /media/ {
            alias /media/;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;     
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;     
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
}

  server {
    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }   
        
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com;
    return 404; 
}
```

Below is nginx logs, when I do `docker-compose logs nginx`

```
nginx_1                  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1                  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx_1                  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx_1                  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx_1                  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx_1                  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1                  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

One more thing. On my server, I can see all ssl files generate by certbot, and are stored in folder called `cerbot`.

Comment: Please someone should help me.. I still haven’t found a solution to this

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the problem. So all my configuration was actually okay -- The issue was that port 443 was not opened on my server
I had only opened it in the outbound rule, I didn't realise I had to open it in the inbound rule too.

My application was running in an ec2 server, on aws.

I used this tool https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to check whether the port was open or closed.

The closed port also caused my requests to the server to timeout.